# Should I use Raspberry Pi or Arduino for a project with 3 or more sensors

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, sensors

I recently started on a project where we are trying to build a box with different sensors. As I am fairly new to this I was wondering which Hardware I should buy for this project. After doing my research, I am still not sure which one I should buy...

For this project I want to connect to the board:

- 1 IMU (we already have the BMI085 from Bosch)
- 2 IR Sensors (I was looking at the GP2Y0A60SZLF from Sharp)
- 1 Camera

From what I have read, it seems the Arduino is easier to use for new programmers, however it seems that I have more flexibility with the Raspberry Pi and it is easier to connect a Camera to it.

The final goal of this Project would be to gather the data in real time from all the sensors and save it on an SD-Card. There should also be some sort of Timestap to be able to match the information from all the sensors to a specific time.

Thank you for all your help! :)

Sam

Comment: I'd suggest the Raspberry Pi simply because of the flexibility.

Comment: There's lots of good info online about this. Here's an example: [Raspberry Pi vs Arduino](https://makezine.com/2015/12/04/admittedly-simplistic-guide-raspberry-pi-vs-arduino/). Basically, the Arduino is a single task unit, whereas the Raspberry Pi would be needed if you're managing lots of tasks and needing additional general computing, etc. Sounds to me like you want the latter. Some projects are best handled with both: Arduino for the endpoints and Raspberry Pi for the central control, management, data collection, etc.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not specifically about programming and probably belongs on RaspberryPi.StackExchange.com

Comment: You could use either one...typically people use C on arduino and python on the Pi...but not you can use others on the pi. If you go with the arduino..you could migrate to the much cheaper ESP32s. To me...there is much more support and code available for arduino.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the camera i suggest you to use raspberry because codification of video would need a lot of cpu, consider that raspberry is more like a computer and arduino is a microprocessor that can't manage huge data like the output of a camera